# Spring '18 Component lightning:recordEditForm Not Working as Expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Contact">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="CleanStatus" />

    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

While run the above component on app, I got following error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>    [Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'value' of undefined]]

Anyone can say the reason and solution for this?

Comment: where is your component embeded? if its in a lightning comunity, is it on a record page? is it in a lightning app? please add more details, i do recall the docuemntation mentioning that a recordId should be passed as a parameter, have you tried adding the recordId ?

Comment: Yes, is it on the lightning app. I want to use this to create a new record. So I can't use recordId.

Comment: so, in that case, maybe you can try using the force:createRecord if t lightning:recordEdit doesnt work for x reason

Comment: I want to use lightning:inputField, so force:createRecord not suitable on this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the above case. It is a Field Accessibility issue. While I check the Field Accessibility of that particular field, that exist with 'Hidden' for that particular record type. When I changed that to 'Editable', it works fine.